# Is this process for generating an OpenGL perspective projection correct?

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d

I have been programming OpenGL for a while now and I have successfully created a perspective camera, however, I can't help but shake the feeling that I am doing it wrong. The code I am using is below, is there something wrong with how I am constructing the perspective projection?

```
int MainWindow_SDL::execute(QCoreApplication &app)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    glewInit();

    // ...

    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    gluPerspective(50, 1.33, 1, 1000);
    gluLookAt(3, m_xAxisLocation, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    // ...

    GameStart();
    app.exit();

    return 0;
}
```

I also set it up in the game loop:

```
void MainWindow_SDL::GameLoop()
{
    OpenGLRenderer t_renderer;
    t_renderer.PreGameRender();

    while (m_state == GameState::RUNNING)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();
        processInput();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gluPerspective(50, 1.33, 1, 1000);
        gluLookAt(m_xAxisLocation, m_yAxisLocation, m_zAxisLocation,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        t_renderer.DuringGameRender();

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    t_renderer.PostGameRender();

    GameEnd();
}
```

Comment: We don't generally do code review (you may want to look [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for that). However, your basic question about whether or not you set up the GL projection matrix is reasonable. I've trimmed the extraneous code to focus on that issue.

Comment: Also, if you're not already aware, the functions you're using (the GL matrix stack and such) imply you're using a very old version of OpenGL. They are almost all deprecated in modern OpenGL (if that matters to you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
gluPerspective(50, 1.33, 1, 1000);
gluLookAt(3, m_xAxisLocation, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

This kind of thing is generally wrong. What've you've done here is set the active matrix stack to the model-view stack; this is responsible for generating the matrix transform that will bring your rendered geometry into view space (for fixed-function lighting).

However, while this stack is active you're calling `gluPerspective`, which builds a perspective projection matrix and multiplies it onto the stack. Then you build a look-at (view) transform using `glLookAt`.

Generally you want to put the projection matrix into the dedicated projection matrix stack by doing things this way:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(50, 1.33, 1, 1000);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(m_xAxisLocation, m_yAxisLocation, m_zAxisLocation, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```